# Extract substring that has special character - Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

In my column, there is a string that contains a word which starts with character `'='` How can I extract those words? I found `REGEXP_SUBSTR` but I couldn't find out particular regular expression to do this? I appreciate any help. Thanks.

EDIT :

I have such a string :

```
"What a =lovely day!"
```

I want to get `"=lovely"`

Comment: Do you need to extract the word that starts with `=` or rows that start with `=`?

Comment: @JSapkota I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regexp_substr for this:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '=\S+')
from your_table;
```

`=\S+`:

- `=` - match literal `=`
- `\S+` - match one or more non space characters

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('What a =lovely day!', '=\w+')
```

or

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('What a =lovely day!', '=\S+')
```

depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want to match based on a list of special characters, use something like below.

In this example, you can match `=` and `#`. You can add more special character if you like.

Also if you want just `=` to be returned in case rest word is missing after that, then use `\S*`. Else use `\S+`

For strings which dont have this format, you will get `null`.

```
select regexp_substr(col1,'[=#]\S*') from
(select 'what a =lovely day' as col1 from dual union all
select 'some other #word as' from dual union all
select 'a normal string' from dual)
```